# Screen does not refresh swing java

Tags: java, swing, refresh

Suppose I add a JButton in JPanel.
when I execute there is no JButton.
I have to go to NetBeansProjects\MyProyect\build\classes.
and delete everything inside then when I execute it refreshes.

Comment: For better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: dont understand your question properly... i GUESS you need frame.revalidate();

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: @StormeHawke  I still wince when I see that close reason. :-/  See [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188511/155831) on Meta for the reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the compile on save (i.e, not generating the class files after saving .java files automatically in  \MyProyect\build\classes) in netbeans, check the below link:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCompileOnSave#How_to_turn_it_on.2Foff

If not, please be clear wrt the question that you have asked.

Answer (score 1):

add the button in the panel after initialization

```
buttonPanel.add(button);
```